# Understanding something with var variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop, var

hi in this code I try to find the number of times the max number is in the array:

```
 x = [1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4];

for(let i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
 let temp = x[0];
 var count=1;
 if(x[i] > temp) {
    temp=x[i];
    continue;
 } else if(x[i] == temp) {
    count++;
 }    
}

console.log(count);
```

when I use the code like this the count is 1, meaning it wont change, but:

```
 x = [1,2,2,4,2,4];
 var count=1;
 for(let i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
  let temp = x[0];      
  if(x[i] > temp){
    temp = x[i];
    continue;
   } else if(x[i] == temp) {
    count++;
   }    
}

console.log(count);
```

when I put the var count outside the loop it works and shows 2, but why? Isn't `var` becoming a global variable and is not effected by the for loop scope like let?

Comment: FYI, You could probably use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this.

Answer (score 2):

If `var count=1;` is *inside*  the loop, `count` is set (i.e. reset) to `1` every time the loop starts over again, resulting in the same count number every time the loop is rendered. That's why you have to put that *before*  the loop.